# presto udaf function use map state run different result every time

Tags: presto

I defined a Presto udaf function, which uses the map type as the intermediate result state,The logic of this function is to implement deduplication, The problem is that I get different results every time I run,the results of only one group are correct, but the results will change when there are multiple groups.
here is the code:

```
@InputFunction
public static void input(MapIntState state,
                         @SqlNullable @SqlType(StandardTypes.VARCHAR) Slice orderIdsSlice)
{
    String orderIds = orderIdsSlice.toStringUtf8();
    if(orderIds != null && !orderIds.isEmpty()){
        String[] orderIdArr = orderIds.split(",");
        for (String orderId : orderIdArr) {
            if(!state.getMapInt().containsKey(orderId)){
                state.addMemoryUsage(orderId.length() + SIZE_OF_INT);
                state.getMapInt().put(orderId,1);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class MapIntStateFactory implements AccumulatorStateFactory<MapIntState> {
private static final long HASH_MAP_SIZE = 128;
@Override
public MapIntState createSingleState() {
    return new SingleMapIntState();
}

@Override
public Class<? extends MapIntState> getSingleStateClass() {
    return SingleMapIntState.class;
}

@Override
public MapIntState createGroupedState() {
    return new GroupedMapIntState();
}

@Override
public Class<? extends MapIntState> getGroupedStateClass() {
    return GroupedMapIntState.class;
}

public static class SingleMapIntState implements MapIntState {
    private int memoryUsage;
    private final Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    @Override
    public void addMemoryUsage(int memory) {
        memoryUsage += memory;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Integer> getMapInt() {
        return map;
    }

    @Override
    public long getEstimatedSize() {
        return memoryUsage + HASH_MAP_SIZE;
    }
}

public static class GroupedMapIntState implements GroupedAccumulatorState, MapIntState {
    private long groupId;
    private long memoryUsage;
    private final ObjectBigArray<Map<String, Integer>> map = new ObjectBigArray<>();
    @Override
    public void setGroupId(long groupId) {
        this.groupId = groupId;
    }

    @Override
    public void ensureCapacity(long size) {
        map.ensureCapacity(size);
    }

    @Override
    public void addMemoryUsage(int memory) {
        memoryUsage += memory;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Integer> getMapInt() {
        if (map.get(groupId) == null) {
            map.set(groupId, new HashMap<>());
            memoryUsage += HASH_MAP_SIZE;
        }
        return map.get(groupId);
    }

    @Override
    public long getEstimatedSize() {
        return memoryUsage + map.sizeOf();
    }
}
```